# How many devices can be connected at a time using multi peer connectivity framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, multipeer-connectivity

How many devices can be connected at a time using multi peer connectivity framework in iOS? Is it possible to connect hundreds of devices as long as they are near by?

Comment: This is not exactly what you're asking, but you could look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479295/multipeer-connectivity-framework-for-up-to-45-devices I guess the question is: do you truly need hundreds of devices connected, or can you work around it? Hundreds of devices connected to each other would surely be a large resource hog, if nothing else

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only connect to 7 other devices at once. To connect to hundreds of devices you should use another framework. You can do some research on the Alljoyn framework I struggled myself to get usefull code on Alljoyn though. Here is a link to check it out. https://allseenalliance.org. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

At once 8 devices can be connected. That means one device can connect with other 7 peers.

Comment: You could have posted a link to support your answer, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479295/multipeer-connectivity-framework-for-up-to-45-devices